How to add message to dead letter queue of Azure Service Bus topic using HttpClient in C#?
I am implementing a class library in C# which will be used into X++ code for Azure Service Bus communication. I have added code to read message from topic and its subscription.
But for some messages, I want move that message into the dead letter queue with an error message. Through ServiceBusClient, I can do it, but does not work in x++ as it is not supported to nuget package.
Can you help me to send a message into the dead letter queue?
This is my code:
using System;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Web;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TestAzureServiceBusConsole
{
    internal class Program2
    {
        private const string ServiceBusNamespace = "<my-service-bus-instance>";
        private const string TopicName = "<topic-name>";
        private const string SubscriptionName = "<subscription-name>";
        static string SasToken = "";
        static string keyName = "<key-name>";
        static string key = "<key>";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var deadLetterQueuePath = $"{TopicName}/subscriptions/{SubscriptionName}/messages/head";
            var baseAddress = new Uri($"https://{ServiceBusNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/");

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
            {
                SasToken = GetSasToken(baseAddress.AbsoluteUri + $"{TopicName}/");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("SharedAccessSignature", SasToken);
                /* To read message from topic and read its message id*/
                var response = httpClient.PostAsync(deadLetterQueuePath,null).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        MessageRead currentMessage = new MessageRead();
                        var message = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                        var obj = response.Headers.GetValues("BrokerProperties");

                        foreach (var brokerProperties in obj)
                        {
                            // BrokerProperties is a JSON string
                            currentMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageRead>(brokerProperties);
                            currentMessage.message = message;
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("Message received from subscription: " + message);

                        var deadLetterPath = $"{TopicName}/subscriptions/{SubscriptionName}/messages/{currentMessage.MessageId}/movetodeadletterqueue?api-version=2021-12";
                        var deadLetterContent = new StringContent(message, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                        var deadLetterResponse = httpClient.PostAsync(deadLetterPath, deadLetterContent).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                        if (deadLetterResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Message moved to dead-letter queue successfully.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + deadLetterResponse.StatusCode);
                            var deadLetterErrorResponse = deadLetterResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                            Console.WriteLine("Error details: " + deadLetterErrorResponse);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + response.StatusCode);
                        var errorResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                        Console.WriteLine("Error details: " + errorResponse);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + response.StatusCode);
                    var errorResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    Console.WriteLine("Error details: " + errorResponse);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static string GetSasToken(string resourceUri)
        {
            string encodedUri = Uri.EscapeDataString(resourceUri).ToLower();

            DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            TimeSpan week = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);

            int ttl = (int)(now.Add(week) - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
            string signatureString = encodedUri + "\n" + ttl;

            using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)))
            {
                byte[] signatureBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signatureString);
                byte[] hash = hmac.ComputeHash(signatureBytes);
                string hashInBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);

                return $"sr={encodedUri}&sig={Uri.EscapeDataString(hashInBase64)}&se={ttl}&skn={keyName}";
             }
        }
    }

    public class MessageRead
    {
        public int? DeliveryCount { get; set; }

        public int? EnqueuedSequenceNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EnqueuedTimeUtc { get; set; }

        public string LockToken { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LockedUntilUtc { get; set; }

        public string MessageId { get; set; }
        public int? SequenceNumber { get; set; }

        public string State { get; set; }
        public long TimeToLive { get; set; }

        public string message { get; set; }
    }
}

Thanks in advance,
Sandy

Messages are not sent to a dead-letter queue but dead-lettered after a processing attempt.

@Sandy DeadLetter operation is not supported thru the http/rest API. We will add that support in an upcoming release. When the max delivery count for any message is reached and it is still not completed then it will be automatically deadlettered if that is enabled for the queue/subscription. The connectivity mode mentioned above is for the .NET API where the SBMP service bus protocol is tunneled over a http/port80 connection so it is not using REST APIs for that.

@Sandy for DeadLetterQueue sdk using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus refer to this git

@Sandy Adding to Sean Feldman comment, the DLQ in Azure Service Bus serves as a repository for messages that cannot be delivered or processed successfully.This includes scenarios where a message exceeds its maximum delivery attempts, encounters expiration due to time-to-live settings, or fails due to specific application-defined conditions.

@Sampath - yeah it works if message retrieve multiple times. But I need logic to send it manually because any failure happen during X++ operation on message and send failure message with it so client can resolve issue and remove it from dead letter and add back to topic.

@Sandy you replied /said No, I am not using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus nuget package as X++ solution does not support it if add my class library project reference to it with this package. Due to which I am depend on REST API. could you tell  what is X++ solution /X++ operation on message ? –

I am adding this class library (c#) into Dynamics 365 Finance and operation solution(x++), where it does not support to nuget packages.
